# Using Pure CSS Blog Template

Tags: yui-pure-css

I am looking to create a blog website.

I was searching for CSS Template That I can use for my blog website.

I found purecss.io blog theme very good.

How can I use it as my website template

Answer (score 0):

What kind of Blog system are you using? Wordpress? 
To use this layout: http://purecss.io/layouts/blog/
You have to copy the html structure from the layout into your Blog template. You must also use the same css files.
If you're using Wordpress you could start with this theme: https://wordpress.org/themes/blankslate/
It has all functionality without any layout.